# php - Get value from all checked checkboxes and insert them into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="CategoryInput[]" name="categories[]" category="1" value="1" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" class="SubCategoryInput1" subcategory="2" value="2" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="CategoryInput[]" name="categories[]" category="11" value="11" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" class="SubCategoryInput11" subcategory="12" value="12" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" class="SubCategoryInput11" subcategory="13" value="13" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" class="SubCategoryInput11" subcategory="14" value="14" clicked="0">
```

**My question is:**
How can i get the values for the checked checkboxes for `CategoryInput[]` and `subcategory[]` and combine them to look like that:

```
$SelectedCheckBoxValues = "1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 7, 3";
```

Then i have to insert them into MySQL, i know how can i do that, but i need to achieve the variable `$SelectedCheckBoxValues`.

Can you help me out with that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="handler.php" method="get">
 <input type="checkbox" class="CategoryInput[]" name="categories[]" category="1" value="1" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" class="SubCategoryInput1" subcategory="2" value="2" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="CategoryInput[]" name="categories[]" category="11" value="11" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" class="SubCategoryInput11" subcategory="12" value="12" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" class="SubCategoryInput11" subcategory="13" value="13" clicked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="subcategory[]" class="SubCategoryInput11" subcategory="14" value="14" clicked="0">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**handler.php**

```
   $values = $_GET['subcategory'];

   foreach ($values as $subcategory){
  //do something

   }
```

Comment: There is not just `subcategory` there is also `CategoryInput` and i have to merge the values from both arrays into one and insert them in MySQL.

Comment: it isn't clear what you are looking to achieve. I would always use javascript when dealing with this kind of form data. Your category naming conventions are confusing.